# sharepoint flow condition isnt running showing "Input Expression False

Tags: sharepoint

I have a sharepoint list with a list with  "Leave type" as one of the columns which is a choice field. I have another column as "Requested Day" i created a flow that needs approval redirected to another person if Leave type is Annual Leave and it is more than 10 days. i discovered it is running as "Inputs expression is False and goes to where false expression should go. I have tried several times and the problem keeps showing up. thus directing my flow to the email meant for false expression

[flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrfQR.png)

Kindly assist

Comment: Show the flow so we can see where the issue is. I am guessing you are doing an if statement to check if is equal to annual and value is greater than 10?

Comment: @Matt that is what im trying to do but it is runnig false everytime even if the days requested is greater than 10 and the leave type is Annual check this link for the flow https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrfQR.png